# Swift Read in UTF8 String from MPMoviePlayerController metadata

Tags: swift, utf-8, metadata, diacritics

I need to read some metadata which can contain French or German characters & accents.

I think that I need to read the metadata as UTF8 String. But being a beginner in Swift and Apple in general I don't know how to do this.

I tried to implement some similar solutions found on stackOverflow but none worked.

What I'm working with:

```
  let firstMeta: MPTimedMetadata = radioPlayer.timedMetadata.first as! MPTimedMetadata        
  let metaData = firstMeta.value as! String
  print(metaData)
```

There I get

> Antonin DvoÅÃ¡k

instead of

> Antonin Dvořák

<del>Any ideas?</del>

---

Easy solution for how to get UTF8 metadata from online audio stream using AVPlayer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831097/4249825

Comment: When you say you get something _like_ that, what do you actually literally get, verbatim?

Comment: I would rather check what encoding is the ```MPTimedMetadata.value``` using and then the conversion is easy.

Comment: This is not something you can fix, it's a problem in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem in the library, you cannot fix it because the string is already decoded from data.

There is a reason why the whole set of classes was deprecated in iOS 9.

You should use `AVPlayerViewController` & `AVPlayer` & `AVPlayerItem` & `AVMetadataItem`.

They are solving this issue. Don't use `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let convertedString = String(data: metaData.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```